# How do you access the Rainsoft water softener "advanced" settings, such as hardness?

Tags: water-softener

The user manual says that this setting is setup "by your Rainsoft dealer" when the softener is installed. Well, I bought mine off of Craigslist and I don't know how to verify if the settings are correct. Does anybody know how to access the hidden settings, such as harness?

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a web page that alluded to the answer. On the front panel of the control unit there is a small raindrop. While touching the raindrop (it doesn't look like a button), push the program/enter button. It will cycle through the factory settings, such as capacity and hardness.

Answer (score 3):

press and hold both at the same time: Info Center (left) & Customer Settings (up) service settings will display.  It will then ask you for an authorization code. Since there is no numeric keypad, I knew that it had to be some (simple) combination of the keys available.  It happens that mine was to press the Customer Settings (up arrow) button twice.  From there, you are asked whether you want to select "Service Mode" or "Installer Setup".  to select the modes, press the Info Centre (right arrow), then depress the Enter/Regen button once to select the mode you want to enter ("Installer" mode is where you can to adjust the settings for time, date, hardness, iron, controller head model, softener capacity, type of media, type of salt, alarm modes, etc. Once in the "Installer" mode, you can use the Info Center arrows (right or left) to move between the settings and the Customer Settings arrows (up or down) to change the values of each setting.  There are quite a few settings to go through, including some that I elected not to change (for fear of inadvertently screwing up my system).  When you get through all the Service phone number digits (the final setting), you will be asked whether you want to save your changes or not.  The default is "No", so you will need to change it to "Yes" before pressing "Enter". You are on your own from here on, so good luck.

Comment: The OP already answered his own question and it would seem that your instructions are incorrect

Comment: @Steven: It might be different for different models.  This answer could still help someone else in this same situation in the future.  That is why we allow *(and in fact, [encourage](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer))* people to answer old questions.  +1 from me.

Comment: if its for a different model, then what model is that? how will this help anyone without that info?

Comment: @Steven The OP did not give a model either...

Comment: This, from a rejected [suggested edit](http://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/21404), might be useful: "Hold the most upper right button down for a few seconds, a 2 digit pass code will be required, my pass code was---the upper most button twice in a row--- try all the different combinations , which may take a few minutes but you will eventually get it."